# GC logging : gc+meta option does not work on open jdk 14

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

-Xlog:gc+meta*=trace,rt*=off:file=gcmetatrace.txt

I tried using the above option to enable GC logging. It does not work. I am using JDK 13. Does meta option work with jdk 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `meta` would be `metadata`, but I do not know what `rt` should stand for. All the available tags could be listed by `java -Xlog:help -version` and there will be a section: `Available log tags`. Just notice that not all tags can be used on their own (`class` or your `metadata` can't).

If I remove `rt` (as said, I don't really know what this is supposed to mean) and use:

```
 "-Xlog:gc+meta*=trace:file=gcmetatrace.txt"
```

it will fail with:

```
[0.006s][error][logging] Invalid tag 'meta' in log selection. Did you mean 'metadata'?
```

I like this. there is no such tag `meta` that the VM is aware of, as such it fails. The suggestion is to use `metadata`, let's try that:

```
"-Xlog:gc+metadata*=trace:file=gcmetatrace.txt"
```

The result is:

```
[0.005s][warning][logging] No tag set matches selection: gc+metadata*.
```

The problem is that not all tags can be used either individually or in some combinations and `gc+metadata` is one of those. Unfortunately, this is just a warning, the JVM process will start just fine, but the log file will be empty (I wish it would error out too).

So, to answer your question: `meta` is not supported (it does not even exist), `metadata` *is* supported, but not on its own. I am not aware of a command that would list all available combination of the tags, but I can suggest you could try:

```
 "-Xlog:metadata=trace:file=gcmetatrace.txt"
```

This will provide a warning, since `metadata` is not supported on it's own, but that will also show the possible combinations (not sure if all, though):

```
[0.003s][warning][logging] No tag set matches selection: metadata. Did you mean any of the following? metadata* jfr+metadata* jfr+system+metadata redefine+class+obsolete+metadata
```

Comment: the command java -Xlog:help -version does not work. I get Unrecognized option: -Xlog:help
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Comment: @Zack how about `java -version`, what does that give you?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_162"

Comment: @Zack well... Unified logging was introduced with java-9, it does not work with java-8. Then why did you tag your question with `jdk-13`?

Comment: sorry. I have two java versions on the box. the correct answer to your question is openjdk version "14"

Comment: @Zack I see, but anyway - did this answer your question?

Comment: yeah. it answered my question. I see metadata and metaspace tags available. Could you also point me to good resources to master GC logging and GC analysis?thank you @Eugene

Comment: @Zack this is not going to be a single resource, sorry. GC, _in general_ is a complicated topic and has to start slowly - I do not know a single resource that would cover everything and I seriously doubt it would exist...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211505/discussion-between-zack-and-eugene).